# Solving system of differential equations of 2nd order

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve this system of differential equations:
\begin{gather*}
y(t)'' = 2x(t)'' + 3y(t) + 5 \\
x(t)'' = 2y(t)''+3x(t)
\end{gather*}
My try:
\begin{gather*}
-2p^2x+(p^2-3)y=0 \\
(p^2-3)x-2p^2=0
\end{gather*}
We get roots: $p = \pm 1$ and $p = \pm \sqrt{3}i$.
For p = 1, $x = ae^t, y = be^t$.
For p = -1, $x = ae^{-t}, y = be^{-t}$.
For $p =\sqrt{3}i$, $x = ae^{-\sqrt{3}it}, y = be^{-\sqrt{3}it}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Could you add your suggestions please ?

Comment: Get $y''$ from the first, then $y$ from the second, and write $y''=(y)''$.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{cases}
2x''-y''+3y=-5 \\
x''-3x-2y''=0
\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}
2p^2x+(-p^2+3)y=-5\\
(p^2-3)x+(-2p^2)y=0
\end{cases}$

$\begin{vmatrix}
2p^2 & -p^2+3\\
p^2-3 & -2p^2
\end{vmatrix} = 0$

Get $p=\pm 1$ and $p=\pm \sqrt{3} i$. 
Minors: $M_1^1(p) = -2p^2, \ M_2^1(p) = p^2 - 3,  \ M_1^2(p) = -p^2 +3, \  M_2^2(p) = 2p^2$. 
Multiply $M_1^1(p)$ by the first equation and multiply $M_2^1(p)$  by the second equation. Get:
$-3x^{(4)} - 6x''+9x =0$.
Multiply $M_2^1(p)$ by the first equation and multiply $M_2^2(p)$  by the second equation. Get:
$-3y^{(4)} - 6y''+9y =-15$.